# Is it safe to compute a hash on an image compressed in a lossless format such as PNG, GIF, etc.?

Tags: hash, png, image-compression, lossless-compression

I was wondering if any lossless image compression format such as PNG comes with some kind of uniqueness guarantee, i.e. that two different compressed binaries always decode to different images.

I want to compute the hash of images that are stored in a lossless compression format and am wondering if computing the hash of the compressed version would be sufficient.

(There are some good reasons to compute the hash on the uncompressed image but there are out of the scope of my question here.)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not true for PNG. The compression procedure have many parameters (filtering type used for each row, ZLIB compression level and settings), so a single raw image can result in many different PNG files. Even worse, PNG allows to include ancillary data (chunks) with miscelaneous info (for example, textual comments).